# Changing the color of a histogram made using gamlss histDist function

Tags: r, histogram

I want to change the default gray color of the bins in a histogram made with `gamlss::histDist()`. I've tried searching but I can't find any information on how to do it.

Here a small example from the package documentation:

```
require(gamlss)
data(abdom)
histDist(y,family="NO", ylim=c(0,0.005), data=abdom)
```

Which produces this plot:
[image]

How can I change the color of those bins?

Comment: Function `histDist` calls `MASS::truehist` that sets `col = "cyan"`. You can change this setting if you call `truehist` directly but apparently not if you call `histDist`. This is because the dots argument `...` of `histDist` is not meant to pass graphic parameters. According to the manual, it's meant `for extra arguments to be passed to the gamlss function`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the bin's color because there is not an available parameter for the user. You can plot by yourself the histogram and then add the density curve.

```
require(gamlss)
mod <- histDist(y,family="NO", data=abdom)
hist(abdom$y, freq=FALSE, col='pink')
curve(dNO(x, mu=mod$mu, sigma=mod$sigma), col=4, lwd=5, add=TRUE)
```

Then you can customize the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
histDist(data=abdom, y,
     family="NO",
     main="The y and the fitted NO distribution",
     xlab = "your choice",
     ylab = "Density",
     border.hist = "black",
     ylim=c(0,0.005), 
     col.main = "cyan", 
     col.axis = "brown", 
     col.lab = "green",
     fg.hist = "blue",
     line.ty = 1, 
     line.col = "red",
     col.hist = "pink")
```

getAnywhere(histDist) will show you the function and you may add some extra arguments as cex.main=cex.main, ...